# 0.0.0.0/0 is not feasible for nfs configuration

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, nfs

I'm new to NFS(network file system).
I was trying to create my own nfs system inside k8s cluster.
FYI, below is my ip settings.

```
# k8s cluster ip settings
master1 ansible_host=10.1.3.245 ip=10.1.3.245
node1 ansible_host=10.1.3.58 ip=10.1.3.58
node2 ansible_host=10.1.3.191 ip=10.1.3.191
node3 ansible_host=10.1.3.88 ip=10.1.3.88
node4 ansible_host=10.1.3.74 ip=10.1.3.74
node5 ansible_host=10.1.3.228 ip=10.1.3.228
```

All nodes are ubuntu18.04 and I run nfs server on node1 (10.1.3.58).
Below is `/etc/hosts` file on node1.

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback localhost6 localhost6.localdomain
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
# Ansible inventory hosts BEGIN
10.1.3.58 node1.cluster.local node1
10.1.3.191 node2.cluster.local node2
10.1.3.88 node3.cluster.local node3
10.1.3.74 node4.cluster.local node4
10.1.3.228 node5.cluster.local node5
10.1.3.245 master1.cluster.local master1
# Ansible inventory hosts END
```

To serve nfs server, I edited `/etc/exports` file.
According to my understanding, `/etc/exports` file has following format in each line:
`<path> <allowed_ips>(options)`.

For example `/mnt/node1nfsstorage 0.0.0.0/0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure)` means allow all access to nfs dir `/mnt/node1nfsstorage` from everywhere.

When I use above config, I cannot access to nfs server (node1) from master1. (I opened 2049 port which is default port of nfs!). FYI here is the command that I used.

```sh
# from master1
ubuntu@master1:~$ sudo mount 10.1.3.58:/mnt/node1nfsstorage /home/ubuntu/mount
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.1.3.58:/mnt/node1nfsstorage

# from /var/log/syslog from node1
ubuntu@node1:/mnt$ tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep nfs
Jan 19 06:23:50 node1 kernel: [190747.809254] nfsd_dispatch: vers 4 proc 0  # I also cannot understand this log message
```

But when I changed config to `/mnt/node1nfsstorage  *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure)`, finally it works.

I think `*` is related to wildcard for domain names and `0.0.0.0/0` represents ip range. Why only `*` works for my situation? Can anybody help me to understand this? After some tests, I found that several ip or ip ranges do not work too, e.g, `0.0.0.0`, `10.1.3.*`, `10.1.0.0/16`

Comment: `0.0.0.0/0` means all network interfaces; which is where your server is going to be mapped. You can change it by localhost, in which case you wouldn't reach it from outside the node, so you need to do that. Or to set the IP address of the node. But doing things like `0.0.0.0`, `10.1.3.*`, `10.1.0.0/16` do not really make sense.

Comment: @suren What I want to do when using `0.0.0.0/0` is to open nfs to all ips. But it did not work. I agree that `0.0.0.0` and `10.1.3.*` will not work but why `10.1.0./16` does not work too? Isn't it valid IP range with ip and mask?

Comment: if the IP address of the node is within that range, should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `/etc/exports` file we can configure our NFS server's shares.
Typical entry has the following structure:

```
export_directory host_designation(options)
```

where:
`export_directory` - NFS share being exported
`host_designation` - one or multiple hosts or networks that have access to this export

`host_designation` (NFS clients) may be specified in a number of ways:

- single host
- netgroups
- multiple systems / wildcards
- IP networks

In your case you are using wildcards method that **shouldn't** be used with IP addresses because it may cause unexpected behaviours (I don't recommend to use e.g `10.1.3.*`). The `*` or `?` wildcards can be used with `FQDN` or `hostname`.

In my opinion `0.0.0.0/0` isn't valid syntax for the NFS. If you need to export share to everyone you can use `*` or even leave `host_designation` blank e.g.:

```
/mnt/node1nfsstorage  (rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure)
```

You can find more information and examples [here](https://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/5/RHEL-5-manual/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-nfs-server-config-exports.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, as you pointed out, I agree with `10.1.3.*` will not work. But my problem is that I don't why why `0.0.0.0/0` also does not work. Anyway to make it run, `*` works!

Answer (score 0):

The man page on ubuntu says this about the exports:

```
  IP networks
              You can also export directories to all hosts on an IP (sub-) network simultaneously. This is done by specifying an IP address and netmask pair  as  address/netmask
              where the netmask can be specified in dotted-decimal format, or as a contiguous mask length.  For example, either `/255.255.252.0' or `/22' appended to the network
              base IPv4 address results in identical subnetworks with 10 bits of host. IPv6 addresses must use a contiguous mask length and must not be inside square brackets to
              avoid  confusion  with  character-class  wildcards.  Wildcard  characters  generally do not work on IP addresses, though they may work by accident when reverse DNS
              lookups fail.
```

But I was on the same point and I was not able to use the ip/netmask and ended using the wildcard *, I found more posts with the same problem, maybe this doesn't solve your question but maybe can confirm for you that the working way of wildcard or IP/netmask has the same outcome:

[Serverfault topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/599395/how-do-i-configure-an-nfs-server-to-accept-all-mount-requests)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes... the question you shared has same problem with me, i.e, ip/mask does not work.